# On the two definitions of derived functor in general triangulated category.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors, triangulated-categories, kan-extensions

I'm learning homological algebra using several references books. But I find two definitions of derived functor in general triangulated category. I wonder to know which definition is more generally accepted.

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a triangulated category and $\mathcal{C}$ a strictly full triangulated subcategory of $\mathcal{D}$ with the quotient $Q:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{D}/\mathcal{C}$. Given a triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ and a triangulated functor $F:\mathcal{D}\to \mathcal{T}$, I have seen two different definitions of derived functor of $F$ with respect to $\mathcal{C}$.

**Version 1**   A right derived functor of $F$ with respect to $\mathcal{C}$ is a pair consisting of a triangulated functor $\mathcal{R}F:\mathcal{D}/\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{T}$ and a trinatural transformation $\eta:F\Rightarrow (\mathcal{R}F)Q$ such that: given any triangulated functor $G:\mathcal{D}/\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{T}$ and trinatural transformation $\xi:F\Rightarrow G Q$, there is a unique trinatural transformation $\chi:\mathcal{R}F\Rightarrow G$ such that $\xi=(\chi Q)\eta$.

For example, this definition occurs in [note1 (page 198)](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Emilicic/Eprints/dercat.pdf) and [note2 (page 72)](http://therisingsea.org/notes/TriangulatedCategories.pdf).

**Version 2**   A right derived functor of $F$ with respect to $\mathcal{C}$ is just a left Kan extension $(\text{Lan}_QF,\eta)$. Also, some references require $\text{Lan}_QF$ to be triangulated without $\eta$ being compatible with translations.

For example, this definition occurs in page 253 of "Categories and Sheaves" by Masaki Kashiwara (eseential the same) and some books in other languages.

I think these two definition are **not** equivalent. A ordinary Kan extenstion $\text{Lan}_QF$ has no reason to be triangulated, and its natural transformation $\eta$ also has no reason to be compatible with translations. On the converse, the left Kan extension in the sense of triangulated categories (version 1) can not be an ordinary left Kan extension.

I wonder to know which definition is more generally accepted.

Comment: Are you sure that the ordinary Kan extension is not automatically triangulated in this situation? It's not exactly the same, and I haven't checked whether it can be adapted to prove this, so I might be missing an important difference, but the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05S7) seems to prove something similar (see in particular Lemma 13.14.6).

Comment: @JeremyRickard I have roughly checked that Lemma. Since I'm not familiar with the language of ind-object and essentially constant used there, I still have no idea why the ordinary Kan extesion implies the Kan extension in 2-cateogory of triangulated category. I'll read the notes in the Stacks Project more carefully when time makes that possible.